# Not able to see saved UVs in UV layers in Blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv, edit-mode

Having difficulty in viewing of saved Uv layers in Uv Map they are unsaved.

If I unwarp a mesh of an object in a new UV layer and go to the next layer unwarp some other part of mesh and if I go back to previous layer that unwrapped mesh is not visible or sometimes its not saving.

So my issue is if i go to any UV layer in UV Maps palette am getting fresh board and no saved UVs at all in UV editor. Actually UV layers how I need is if i switch over to any UV layer I should get proper saved unwrapped UVs.

So how can I fix this issue?